# How to convert a directed graph to an undirected graph?

Tags: graph

How do you convert a directed graph to an undirected graph using an adjacency matrix?

```
public directedToUndirected(boolean[][] adjMatrix) {

}
```

Comment: is the only thing i need to do inside the method just:

Comment: if (adjMatrix[i][j] == true) { adjMatrix[j][i]=true; } ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a boolean `OR` operation with the original matrix and the transpose of the original.

Comment: Your method in your comment would work as well.  An undirected graph will just mirror the matrix along the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the whole array and flip the indices, assuming you're using 0 and 1's

```
for (int i=0; i<adjMatrix.length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<adjMatrix[i].length; j++) {
    if (adjMatrix[i][j] == 1) {
      adjMatrix[j][i] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must find any method that need not to change the information. In all of the above suggested methods edge between node `i` to `j` is given to `j` to `i` and it is wrong because there is not such edge.

You can change the graph into larger one and make some virtual connections. For example if `i` has connection to `j` and `j` has connection to `i` you can change `i` to `i'` and define new edge between `j` and `i`. You also should save this fact that `i'` is the same as `i`.

Comment: What you describe is theoretically correct, but finding a solution is not possible. Think of a directed graph containing two nodes A and B and an edge (A, B). There is no way to construct an undirected graph with the same properties.