# Transform a simple directed graph to a simple undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

How would I convert a simple directed graph to a simple undirected one?

Is this possible?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128755/how-to-convert-a-directed-graph-to-an-undirected-graph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming: (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph))

> in a simple digraph loops are disallowed. (A loop is an arc that pairs a vertex to itself.)

and: (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29#Simple_graph))

> a simple [undirected] graph is an undirected graph that has no loops (edges connected at both ends to the same vertex) and no more than one edge between any two different vertices.

I'm assuming the edges are unweighted, otherwise this can't be done without specifying how this needs to be done.

AM = Adjacency matrix

AL = Adjacency list

- Remove the direction of all edges.

  AM: For each edge A->B, row A, column B would already be set. Also set row B, column A.

  AL: For each edge A->B, the edge already appears in A's AL, also add the edge to B's AL.
- Go through all edges, removing all edges for which we already found an edge between the two vertices that are the end-points of that edge (so if A-B has already been processed, if we find another A-B (or equivalently B-A), we must remove that edge). This needs to be done since there can be multiple edges between vertices in a simple directed graph, but this can't happen in a simple undirected graph.

  AM: Nothing really needs to be done since an AM forces there to only be a single edge between vertices, so we'd just be overwriting the edges.

  AL: For each vertex A, for each edge A-B or B-A in its adjacency list, remove all other edges A-B or B-A in the list.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 2nd bulleted point?
Let's say I have a simple digraph A->B->C, removing directions would get me A-B-C.. What should I do next?

Comment: Simple directed graph can have loops. So your first assumption may not be true. Your answer is not technically correct.

Comment: @Bill Based on some definitions, simple digraphs can have loops, that's why I stated my assumption (so that my answer is technically correct).

Comment: I have given the standard graph theoretic way to convert directed graphs to undirected graphs. A undirected graph is simple if it does not have self loop...so using my technique you can convert the graph and then just delete any self-loops, if any.

Answer (score 1):

[image: A demonstration][Source and details...](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/converting-a-digraph-to-an-undirected-graph-in-a-reversible-way)

> For each directed edge e=(x,y), add new vertices ve1,…,ve5 and replace e with the edges xve1, ve1ve2, ve1ve3, ve3ve4, ve4ve5, ve3y.
>
> To decode, every leaf (degree-1 vertex) whose neighbour has degree 2 must be ve5 for some edge e=(x,y); its neighbour is ve4 and the other neighbour of ve4 is ve3. ve3 has a unique neighbour that has both degree 3 and is adjacent to a leaf: the neighbour is ve1 and its leaf is ve2 (if ve1 has two leaf neighbours, pick one arbitrarily to be ve2). The other neighbour of ve1 is x and the other neighbour of ve3 is y. Restore the directed edge (x,y) and delete the vertices ve1,…,ve5.

Answer (score 0):

`G=(V,E)` is a directed graph. `(a,b) \in E` is a directed edge.
`G' = (V, E')` is an equivalent undirected graph where `(a,b)` is transformed as `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`.
Thus, edge directed edge becomes two edge (one in each direction).

Comment: But I want a simple undirected graph.

Comment: Simple undirected graph does not mean you can not have cycles. If you have self loop, then `(a,a)` a directed edge is `(a,a)` an undirected edge. However, this will result in self-loops which will make graphs no longer simples. So you can just ignore self-loops.

Comment: This is a standard technique to convert directed graphs to undirected graphs.

Comment: My apologies for the inambiguity.  I do not want loops.

Comment: There is a different between loops and self-loops. If you dnt want loops, when you have to have DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph). However, DAG when converted to undirected graphs, can not guarantee no cycles. You have to manually delete such loops. Just stating concepts from graph theory :)

Comment: I mean I want cycles but don't want self-loops.. :-)

Comment: since you have simple directed graphs, you are guaranteed to have no self-loops. therefore, the undirected graph you will get using the method i mentioned, is guaranteed to have no self-loops. you can prove this as a lemma or theorem :) (hint- prove by contradiction)

Comment: let's say i have this directed adjacency list
a: b, c
\nb:
\nc: b

what would the undirected adjacency list become?

Comment: so if your directed edges are (a,b) and (c,b) .. then your undirected graph has four edges (a,b), (b,a), (c,b), (b,c) -- note that there are no self-loops :)

Comment: pardon my amateur knowledge. if there is no path from a to c assuming my directed edges are only (a, b) and (c, b), wouldn't the four undirected edges mean there will be a path from a to c?

Comment: yes, you will have a path. Please note that you want to transform your directed graph to undirected graph. There is no guarantee that no path in a directed graph implies no path in undirected graph :)

Comment: Oh.. but are the two graphs theoretically the same graphs or not? I mean they are the same but only different in its representation?

Comment: No, theoretically they are different graphs. This is from definitions of graph theory :)

Comment: Wait.. I meant to ask are the graphs equivalent form of each other.  Example: Water can come in liquid or solid form but it is still water.

Comment: Also, you can prove some theorems in these graphs, e.g. if the directed graph had a cycle, the undirected graph will have a cycle. But the converse is not true.

Comment: This method is to transform a directed graph to its equivalent undirected graph. But, that does not mean `G congruent to G'` where `G` is directed graph and `G'` is its equivalent undirected graph.

Comment: I still don't get it.  What if you transform a directed graph to an undirected graph and back to a directed graph?  Will the both directed graphs be the same?

Comment: how do you transform an undirected graph to a directed graph? The standard way is to assign directions to the edges in the undirected graph. So, if you do that, then you will end up with two different directed graphs :)

Comment: Mind pointing me to a good resource where I can read about these conversions?  I don't want to spam this site with my comments. :)

Comment: The book which is best in my opinion is by `Douglas West`. You should find plenty of sites on google or bing. This is just one site I found -- http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs130a/Graphs.txt    I hope this helps.